# pdf file print in VBA PrintOut Method in Worksheet class failed. Run time error 4001

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an excel file to be printed as pdf. Used the following code to do it.  It works 30% of time. Once I run it few times, it throws error

> PrintOut Method in Worksheet class failed. Run time error 4001.

Code below:

The Wait time is given as suggested by someone. But did not work. Tried Ne01, 02,  etc for `ActivePrinter`. But doesn't.  However, this works once I close all Excel or shut down machine and come back for once or twice. After that it gives error.  Any help is appreciated.

```
  flNmPrt = invPdf & custNm & "_" & invNo & "_" & sDate & "_" & curHr & curMin & curSec & ".pdf"
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 'wait 2 seconds
    
  ActiveSheet.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=flNmPrt

'    ActiveSheet.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne01:", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=flNmPrt
'    ActiveSheet.PrintOut ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=flNmPrt
  
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 'wait 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat) to export a worksheet as PDF:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=flNmPrt, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

This is much more reliable as printing and it works on every computer. If you define `Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:` the `Ne02` part will change on every computer and break the code.

And there is no need to `Application.Wait`.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the above mentioned issue with the printer port, I have put in place these two functions:

```
Public Function GetPrinterPort(ByVal PrinterName As String) As String
    Dim t As Long

    Do
        GetPrinterPort = String$(Len(GetPrinterPort) + 256, 0)
        t = GetProfileString("PrinterPorts", PrinterName, "", GetPrinterPort, Len(GetPrinterPort))
    Loop Until t < Len(GetPrinterPort) - 1

    If t <= 0 Then
        ERR.Raise 5, , "Cannot get printer port for " & PrinterName
        End
    End If
    
    GetPrinterPort = Split(Left$(GetPrinterPort, t), ",")(1)
End Function

Sub SetVirtualPrinter()
    Dim zPrinter As String
    Dim zPort As String
    
    zPrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    zPort = GetPrinterPort(zPrinter)
    zPrinter = zPrinter & " on " & zPort

    Application.ActivePrinter = zPrinter
End Sub
```

I made the experience that the `Sheet.PrintOut` method doesn't work anymore when using the PrintToFile attribute and the PrToFileName attribute. A pdf file is simply not created although the method doesn't throw an error. The funny thing: if I omit the PrToFileName attribute to be prompted for the target file, the pdf will be created.
I tried to change the current directory to not having to specify the full path but this didn't work either.
The recommended Sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat method could only be used as long as a workbook is not set to "confidential" as this would block a pdf export.
I therefore wonder if Microsoft made one of these fantastic,buggy updates:-|